# How to emit a signature with git-format-patch when --attach is used?

Tags: git

I'm using git version 1.8.3.3. When I run

```
git format-patch -1 --signature="XYZ"
```

the resulting `.patch` file contains signature `XYZ` as expected. However, when I run

```
git format-patch -1 --signature="XYZ" --attach
```

the signature is no longer included in the created `.patch` file.

Is there a way of emitting a signature when `--attach` is used? The manual page for `git format-patch` does not discuss this.